# How to fetch last entered entry for a id from table MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:

A order goes through multiple states. so each state have entry in  table_orderstatus. Statusdate will be there, but not shown in this example.

Example

table_orders - orderid, ordervalue;

```
1- 500
2- 1000
3- 8000
4- 10000
```

table_orderstatus - orderid, statusid, statusdate; (orderid, statusid)

```
1- 1 
1- 2
2- 1
2- 3
3- 1 
3- 3
3- 4
4- 1
4- 3
4- 4
4- 5
5- 1
```

table_statusvalues - statusid, statusvalue;

```
1- NEW
2- CANCEL
3- CONFIRM
4- DISPATCHED
5- DELIVERED
```

I want to fetch order_id, and last status value (not id) for all the orders.

```
1- CANCEL
2- CONFIRM
3- DISPATCHED 
4- DELIVERED
5- NEW
```

I tried multiple ways to achieve same. But coudn't got expected result. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last according value:

```
select orderid, statusvalue from (
    select orderid, max(statusid) laststatus
    from table_orders o
          inner join table_orderstatus s on s.orderid = o.orderid
     group by o.orderid
) l
inner join table_statusvalues on statusid = laststatus
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT T.orderid, S.statusvalue
FROM (
   SELECT O1.orderid, O2.statusid
   FROM _orderstatus O1
   WHERE O1.statusdate > (
      SELECT MAX(O2.statusdate)
      FROM _orderstatus O2
      WHERE O2.orderid = O1.orderid
      AND O2.statusdate <> O1.statusdate
   )
) T, _statusvalues S
WHERE T.statusid = S.statusid
```